# (Typescript) Property 'window' does not exist on type 'Global'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using Mocha/Chai to unit test and am mocking `window` as follows:

```
global.window = { innerHeight: 1000, innerWidth: 1000 };
```

Understandably, TSLint is complaining that:

> Property 'window' does not exist on type 'Global'

A few questions... is `Global` a built in NodeJS/Typescript type?  I'm currently silencing the warning with `declare var global` at the top of the file... but is this the best way to handle this?  I noticed I can also resolve the warning with:

```
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface  Global {
            window: any;
        }
    }
}
```

Preferably, I'd like to extend the existing `Global` type to also accept a `window` property.  Thanks.

Comment: You can also reference the `window` object like this in TS: `(<any>window)`. Not pretty IMHO but does suppress the warning

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the declaration merging you're doing... maybe I'd suggest making it `{window: Window}` instead of `{window: any}`, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 8):

> is `Global` a built-in NodeJS/Typescript type?

Yes. See `@types/node/index.d.ts`; in that file, they declare a `NodeJS` namespace, and within that, a `Global` interface (just as you've done).

> I'm currently silencing the warning with `declare var global`

Sounds like you don't have the Node typings installed (those typings include the line `declare var global: NodeJS.Global;` so you shouldn't have to make any such declarations yourself). Run:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

or, if you use `yarn`:

```
yarn add -D @types/node
```

> Preferably, I'd like to extend the existing `Global` type to also accept a `window` property.

You're mostly there. Just replace `window: any;` with `window: Window;`. Note: you will need your `tsconfig.json`'s `lib` section to include `dom` to provide the `Window` interface.

You may soon find that you also want to augment Global `document` and `navigator` (again, both of these are defined in the `dom` lib, and hence require it):

```
interface Global {
    document: Document;
    window: Window;
    navigator: Navigator;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work... Can you clarify?

So the Global interface should be defined at root in a `global.d.ts` file? 
And Document, Window and Navigator should be imported from "jsdom"?

We have rules that all our interfaces should start with capital I. Is that a problem with "IGlobal"? I get an error that it's unused.

Comment: The `Global` interface can be defined either: *1)* in each file that you need to reference it from (in which case you can have top-level `import` and `export` statements around it); or *2)* in its own `.d.ts` file of any name, anywhere in the project that the `tsconfig.json` will look for it (e.g. `src/myGlobals.d.ts`). The Document, Window, and Navigator interfaces are defined by the core `dom.lib.d.ts`, but maybe also by JSDom. JSDom can polyfill its implementation for a non-browser environment. It *must* be named Global, *not IGlobal*, to augment the existing meaningful `Global` interface.